# Is it possible to have a turn server without configuring realm?

Tags: webrtc, nat, stun, rfc5766turnserver

I was trying to host a turn server for my webRTC project. I have my entire server running on a virtual machine static public IP Address. I found this article [Turn Server Installation Guide](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html#coturn). For configuring the turn server we need to have a domain name that is not available in my case. Is it possible to have a turn server running on my public IP without configuring any domain/realm name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I found it is not necessary to configure the realm.